# Sending integers via serial port and printing to LCD

Tags: c, matlab, serial-port, arduino, lcd

I am trying to send integers via the a USB serial port from MATLAB to an Ardunio Uno and then subsequently display them on an LCD. I have a problem with numbers from 128 to 159 displaying as 63 on the Arduino display.

Here is my MATLAB code:

```
q = serial('COM4'); % set com port location
set(q,'BaudRate',9600); % set baud rate
fopen(q); % open the port
fprintf(q,a_number) % send the integer
```

Here is my Arduino code:

```
int incomingByte = 0; // storage for integer
void serialRead () // 
{
   incomingByte = Serial.read(); // read the serial port 
   if (Serial.available() > 0) // if there is data print it to LCD
   {
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1 
      lcd.print("Boot:     %");
      delay(500);
      lcd.setCursor(6,1);
      lcd.print(incomingByte,DEC); // print the Integer to the LCD
      delay(500);
   }
}
```

All numbers from 0 to 255 are displayed correctly apart from numbers 128 to 159 which are displayed as the value 63.

Update:  I tested the serial port on my from my computer using a serial analyzer and it looks like MATLAB is responsible for sending the data incorrectly. I tested the Arduino code separately and it works perfectly.

Comment: Your last statement is somewhat contradictory: "All numbers from 0 to 255 display on the LDC correctly, I have no idea why numbers 128 to 159 incorrectly display as 63."

Comment: I don't know anything about Arduino, but a brief [RTFM](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read) reveals that Serial.read() returns -1 when there is no data available. You don't check this, so how do you know there is data available?

Comment: @Michael Walz I have edited my question accordingly. I was trying to say that numbers 128 to 159 display incorrectly as the value 63, all other numbers from 0 to 255 display as their correct value.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for pointing that out. I added an if statement to only display a value when there is data available, but this doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: And what happens when you also add `if (Serial.available() > 0)` before reading serial data?

Comment: @Lundin It doesn't change make a difference unfortunately, still only displays 63 over the 128 to 159 range.

Comment: Overall, it smells like an obvious case of `char` used where `unsigned char` should have been used, or possibly code that relies on a certain signedness of `char`. Might very well be some internal bug in one function or the other. I haven't worked with Arduino myself, but everything about it seems to be "hobbyist quality", including the pre-made hardware and libraries...

Comment: @ Lundin I agree with your there, I might go back to using PIC instead of Arduino the compiler and per-built functions suck if you try to do anything remotely complicated.

Comment: @ Lundin I tested the serial port on my from my computer using a serial analyzer and it looks like MATLAB is responsible for sending the data incorrectly. I tested the Arduino code separately and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem added the following line in my MATLAB code in place of the fprintf line:

```
fwrite(q,a_number,'uint16','sync');
```

Comment: if you're sending byte values `[0 255]`, it's probably better to use an 8 bit type like `uint8` for Matlab side (and on the Arduino side make sure you read only an 8 bit type too). That way you won't get buggered with endianness (byte ordering) potentially different between processors.